# Match on two variables

Tags: variables, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access which share two potential relationships (ID & NAME). Is it possible to run a query where if ID does not match to then attempt where NAME may match?  The tables are linked in those two fields but I am unsure if you can perform a multi-variable match - sort of like an IF THEN statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CROSS JOINING the tables to get the dataset you are looking for like this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, Table2.ID, Table2.Name
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID OR Table1.Name = Table2.Name
ORDER BY  Table1.ID, Table1.Name, Table2.ID, Table2.Name;
```

Hope that helps.